# sprintf giving undefined results

Tags: c, printf

I have just finished a small dll written in C. It's an interface between 3rd party software and an astrological dll. Basically it gets the astrological house positions longitude along the ecliptic, given a natal date, time, longitude and latitude. Because the 3rd party software expects a return string I then convert the house longitudes to ascii and string them together with commas using sprintf.
If I declared the return string "retrnString" within function "housecusps" my variables were becoming corrupted (mostly "indx"). However as soon as "retrnString" was declared as global it worked perfectly. Can somebody explain why???

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include "swephexp.h"
#include "Wave59_SDK.h"

typedef  int32 (*JULDAYPTR)(int32, int32, int32, int32, int32, double, int32, double*, char*);
typedef int (*HOUSECUSPSPTR)(double, double, double, int, double*, double*);
char retrnString[96];

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain (HINSTANCE hInst     /* Library instance handle. */ ,
                       DWORD reason        /* Reason this function is being called. */ ,
                       LPVOID reserved     /* Not used. */ );

char* __declspec(dllexport) housecusps(WAVE59_DATASTRUCT *price_ptr, int currentptr,
            int *int_args,int num_int_args,double *double_args,
            int num_double_args,char **string_args,int num_string_args)
{
    int32 iyear = int_args[0];
    int32 imnth = int_args[1];  
    int32 iday = int_args[2];
    int32 ihr = int_args[3];
    int32 imin = int_args[4];  
    int32 gregflag = SE_GREG_CAL;
    double dret[2], cuspArray[13], ascmc[10], julianDays;
    char serr[256];
    const double zeroSecs = 0;
    int hsys = 'P';
    int ctr, indx;
    JULDAYPTR JulDay;
    HOUSECUSPSPTR HouseCusps;

    HINSTANCE astrologyDLL = LoadLibrary("c:\\sweph\\bin\\swetrs32.dll");
    if (astrologyDLL == NULL)
       return "Error loading swedll32.dll";
    JulDay = (JULDAYPTR)GetProcAddress(astrologyDLL, "_swe_utc_to_jd@40");
    if (JulDay == NULL)
       return "Error loading swe_utc_to_jd";
    if (JulDay(iyear,imnth,iday,ihr,imin,zeroSecs,gregflag,dret,serr) == ERR)
       return serr;
    julianDays = dret[1];
    HouseCusps = (HOUSECUSPSPTR)GetProcAddress(astrologyDLL, "_swe_houses@36");
    if (HouseCusps == NULL)
       return "Error loading swe_houses";
    /*//Parms:- dret[1] = Julian day in UT, double_args[0] = Latitude, double_args[1] = Longitude.*/
    if (HouseCusps(julianDays,double_args[0],double_args[1],hsys,cuspArray,ascmc) == ERR)
        return "Error in swe_houses"; 
    indx = 0;
    for (ctr = 1;ctr < 13; ctr++)
    {
        indx += sprintf(retrnString + indx,"%.3f",cuspArray[ctr]);
        if (ctr != 12)
           indx += sprintf(retrnString + indx ,"%c",',');
    }
    FreeLibrary(astrologyDLL);
    return retrnString;
}
```

Comment: Note that `if (JulDay(iyear,imnth,iday,ihr,imin,zeroSecs,gregflag,dret,serr) == ERR) return serr;` is returning a pointer to a local variable.  That is not good.  It is substantially the same as what you were doing with `retrnString` before you made it a global.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler    No - It returns int.

Comment: I' referring to the `return serr;` in your code, not what the function `JulDay` returns.

Answer (score 2):

If you put `char retrnString[96];` in func `housecusps(...)`, it is a local variable which stayed in the stack, when you return from that function, this stack space will be cleared, that is why it was becoming corrupted.

And there are some ways to "return/get" such content from function,

1. a global variable `char retrnString[96];` just like what you have done.
2. `malloc` a memory to hold content and return it, then remember to `free` it later

**Notice**:
A better option is to have the function accept the output buffer as argument(s). Otherwise, 2nd option here ( `malloc` internally ) could be problematic  if the caller uses a different allocator or different memory pool. ---- advice from *@Matt McNabb*

The primary downside to using a global variable for the return value is that your code becomes non-reentrant. You can't have two threads that call the function simultaneously. Further, after calling the function once, you have to either finish with the first value before calling the function a second time, or duplicate the string from the first call before making the second. ----comment from  *@Jonathan Leffler*

Comment: A better option is to have the function accept the output buffer as argument(s).   Your option (2) is problematic if the caller uses a different allocator or different memory pool

Comment: The primary downside to using a global variable for the return value is that your code becomes non-reentrant.  You can't have two threads that call the function simultaneously.  Further, after calling the function once, you have to either finish with the first value before calling the function a second time, or duplicate the string from the first call before making the second.

Comment: That's true. Thanks. To write reentrant code, try to avoid global variable. If have to use it , then mutex might be needed. So, the answer should be refined again:)

Comment: Sorry I have mislead everyone. The problem occurs not after return from function housecusps but after sprintf. By the time housecusps was about to return my variable(s) were already corrupted.